# Extend template check at agent pools in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I just noticed "Approvals and checks" at agent pool level and added couple of checks "approval" and "extend template" check. but it's not working. Same checks if i add at azure devops environments , it works.
Is this feature live ?
If you have some example then please share[image]

Comment: I'm planning to ask this directly to microsoft team, we have a weekly meeting with them.

Comment: It will be great and you are welcome to share your feedback here after your meeting.

Answer (score 0):

> Extend template check at agent pools in azure pipelines

I could reproduce this issue on my side with `extends` in the YAML file.

If I set the following YAML file:

```
trigger: none

extends:
    template: params.yml
    parameters:
        yesNo: true
        image: 'windows-latest'
```

And added "`approval`" check and "`extend template`" check, but none of these appear when I run my pipeline, they seem to be ignored.

Then I change my YAML without `extends`, and also set "`approval`" check and "`extend template`" check:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'



stages:
  - stage: Deploy_Canary
    jobs:
    - template: deploy-infra.yml
```

Those two checks came up:

[image]

To prove it further, I move the "`extend template`" check, **only** keep the `approval` check with **extends**. **However**, the `approval` check still not showing up:

[image]

So, I am afraid this feature still has problems in some places, you could submit this issue on developer community:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21

which is our main forum for product issue. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sanjeev, I can still see it, MS is investigating this issue, let us look forward to their response.